# Can someone track your location by messaging you on Instagram, no links have been sent and no location is enabled

Tags: privacy, geolocation, instagram

Someone messaged me on Instagram. A general conversation i guess. After awhile he claims to know which country i reside in.
No links, photos, videos or locations were exchanged.
Can my location be tracked under these circumstances?

Comment: Short answer is "yes". They are able to know your IP, and that will give them your general location information, like country and maybe city. But that's it.

Comment: @schroeder, how would they know OP's IP?